# Can builder be used to map an xml file to an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, builder

I'm looking for a way to map an xml file to a ruby class.

The class: https://github.com/airbrake/airbrake/blob/master/lib/airbrake/notice.rb

The ruby class actually has a to_xml method that uses builder to generate an xml file.

I need to do the opposite and take the xml and initialize the ruby object.

What's the best way for me to do this?

Performance is a consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Some guys at work have used the [happymapper gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/happymapper). From their examples:

```
dir = File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
require File.join(dir, 'happymapper')

file_contents = File.read(dir + '/../spec/fixtures/statuses.xml')

class User
  include HappyMapper

  element :id, Integer
  element :name, String
  element :screen_name, String
  element :location, String
  element :description, String
  element :profile_image_url, String
  element :url, String
  element :protected, Boolean
  element :followers_count, Integer
end

class Status
  include HappyMapper

  element :id, Integer
  element :text, String
    element :created_at, Time
    element :source, String
    element :truncated, Boolean
    element :in_reply_to_status_id, Integer
    element :in_reply_to_user_id, Integer
    element :favorited, Boolean
    has_one :user, User
end

statuses = Status.parse(file_contents)
statuses.each do |status|
  puts status.user.name, status.user.screen_name, status.text, status.source, ''
end
```